# r: data.table, most efficient row wise normalization

Tags: r, data.table

This code normalizes each value in each row (all values end up between -1 and 1).

```
dt <- setDT(knime.in)

df <-as.data.frame(t(apply(dt[,-1], 1, function(x) x / sum(x) )))

df1<-cbind(knime.in$Majors_Final,df)
```

**BUT**

1. It is not dynamic. The code "knows" that the String categorical variable is in row one and removes it before running the calculations
2. It seems old school and I suspect it does not make full use of data.table's referencing memory allocations.

**QUESTIONS**

How do I use the most memory efficient data.table code to achieve the row wise normalization?

How do I exclude all is.character() columns (or include only is.numeric), if I do not know the position or name of these columns?

Comment: Rowwise operations on a data.frame or data.table must be slow because these are lists of column vectors. You solution turns the data.table into a matrix which involves a deep copy and is slow. Coercing a matrix to a data.frame is another deep copy and cbinding yet another. Reshape your data so that you have a column with the original row number and a column with the values. Than use data.table's by.

Comment: For dataframe / matrices prob fast to do `knime.in[,-1]/rowSums(knime.in[,-1])`. Im not sure how to translate to dat.table but perhaps.. `r=rowSums(knime.in[,-1]) ; 
knime.in[, (paste(names(knime.in)[-1], "norm", sep="_")):=lapply(.SD, "/", r), .SDcols=-1]`

Comment: rowSums coerces a data.frame to a matrix. That's not efficient.

Comment: "*it does not make full use of data.table's referencing memory allocations*" - your code does absolutely no use of any data.table feature. You are just operating over a matrix here and doing so very inefficiently. Two rules of thumb: 1- if you need to do many mathematical operations over columns/rows, use matrices in the first places - data.frames/data.tables weren't designed for that. 2 - Never ever use `apply(df, 1,...)`. Finally, if `df / rowSums(df)` didn't come to your mind instead of that `apply` thingi, you need to learn some base R first.

Comment: I am indeed a neophyte. Ironically, however, that code above came out of a book! I don't know much, but I knew it was wrong